# Moving a copied layer group precisely in GIMP to make a paper of business cards?

Tags: gimp

*Remember to read the whole post.*

I found a template with space for 10 business cards, without extra space anywhere. Using GIMP 2.8.10, I made the design in top left slot and now I need to get that to the other slots. What is the best way to achieve that ? Using mouse is out of question for lack of precision and keyboard takes too long and still isn't completely precise, where we obviously can't afford lack of precision.

Though, I'm no artist.

**The problem is that the slot's contents aren't anywhere same size as the slot itself.**

Comment: Use rectangle selection and select *entire slot contents*, including white space around it. Copy and paste, pasted layer will be of exactly same size.

Comment: @gronostaj: With the layer group selected ?

Comment: Actually, selection isn't bound to layers. You can use *Edit* -> *Copy Visible*, it will do exactly what it says ;) (it will respect selection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gronostaj's comment in the OP gave me an idea. This assumed there's 2 slots next to each other:

1) indeed, have the layer group selected, use the rectangle selection to select the slot along with its surrounding lines [mine are 4 pixels thick], then copypaste to get a new layer. This layer should have the exact size of the slot and all.

2) Move that layer to the next slot on same row.

3) Duplicate the first layer group.

4) Duplicate the second layer group.

5) Lock them together by clicking on both's now invisible chain symbol in the layer window.

6) Move the locked groups to the next slots.

7) Unlock the groups. Forgetting this doesn't screw anything up right now.

8) Duplicate the groups one-by-one you just moved together. I couldn't find a way to duplicate more than 1 layer( group) at once.

9) Move to position. **You must have unlocked the previous ones or you'll move them too.**

10) Repeat #7-9 until you're done with all the slots.